# Background Session Type in Launchd Agent

Tags: macos, launch-agent

I followed [technote](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2083/_index.html) by apple to get an understanding of the various session types in Launchd Agent, but I am not able to understand the 'Background' Session Type.

Briefly:

- Aqua:        a GUI agent; has access to all the GUI services
- LoginWindow: pre-login agent; runs in the login window context
- **Background**:  Runs in a context that's the parent of all contexts for a given user
- StandardIO:  runs only in non-GUI login session (e.g. SSH sessions)

An Overview of the context this works in ,or when to use it will help.